# Copying a value from table and printing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 4 columns, Product ID, Product name, Region of origin and Country (eg France, Italy, Japan etc). I have set up a data validation list based on Country.

I would like to select the Country using the data validation list and utilise the macro to print to PDF (eg 20 products) based on the Country.

1. I am trying to copy a value from the table and paste into a cell, but even then the macro does not work
2. The "Data" table is on another worksheet, whilst the macro is on another, but I have labelled the table as Data, is this going to be problem?

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Sub lookup()

   Dim arr As Variant
   Dim x As Long
   Dim r As Long

   arr = Range("Data")
   r = Range("G2").Value 'cell to show the value

   For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
   If arr(x, 4) = Range("I6").Value Then 'Data validation by Region is in I6

       Cells(r, 1) = arr(x, 1)
       r = r + 1

   End If
   Next x
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: your issue is probably because it can't tell which sheet to operate on. You can qualify the `.Range()` property with a specific sheet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range

Comment: For info about exporting to pdf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat

Comment: This kind of macro must be in a standard code module, not any worksheet's code sheet. A standard code module is one that you add to the project yourself. Its default name will be like `Module1` (but it's recommended to give it a meaningful name). Use the pre-installed code modules affiliated to ThisWorkbook and the worksheets for event procedures and their supporting functions.